# What happens when a phone runs out of storage and pictures are taken?

Tags: iphone, icloud, storage

I am unsure of which iphone I need-64gb or 128gb. I mainly need storage space for photos and videos and I dont think 64gb would be enough. Someone has said that due to iCloud drive a 64gb would however be sufficient but I am unsure of this. When my memory is full will it allow me to carry on taking photos and videos and store straight to iCloud or will I get the usual notice saying there is not enough storage space?

Answer (score 1):

iCloud storage price : http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5879?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

So it depends if you have a good network connection for download what you need when you want (photos with iCloud, musics with spotify...) or if you want all your photos, all your iWork documents and all your stuff on your iPhone all the time.

It depends if you take a lot of videos, if you download a lot of big games from the App Store...

In fact, it depends of your money ^^

Comment: "In fact, it depends of your money"

+1

Answer (score 1):

Your new phone will need free storage to take new photos. There is no provision to take a picture directly and have it go to iCloud.

You'll want to run a calculation on how many photos and how many hours of video you need in addition to the other data on the device and then weigh that against the increased cost for the 128 GB model.

Answer (score 1):

I have a 64GB iPhone 5S. Before that I had a 64GB iPhone 5. And before that a 64GB iPhone 4S. And before that a 64GB iPod Touch.

Each time I bought one of these & told people the capacity I would hear the same thing: "Why don't you use iCloud?" or "Why don't you use Google Drive?" or any number of the same thing: Device storage is irrelevant since it's all about magical syncs with storage systems network far away.

Here is the reality: If networking speeds were great then maybe these arguments have a point. But the reality is not only are networking speeds for mobile devices bad, but they are inconsistent. And if you have ever dealt with wired networking speed issues you'd know that even with a direct connection at gigabit Ethernet speeds, it's never as fast as an onboard system of storage. Never.

So in my case, I got these 64GB iDevices because I wanted the max storage available. Mainly for music.

Now that there is a 128GB iPhone 6 I might get one. But only when the next iteration comes out. Meaning when the iPhone 6S comes out, I will probably get one. And if I do that I will get the 128GB model.

I'm not a Luddite. I understand the benefits of the cloud concept. And I have an unlimited data plan with 4G LTE. But even with that, the consistent hiccups in the way cloud data transfer works makes it way too much of a headache for me.

Call me old fashioned but realistic since I like my storage size to be nice & large. And I prefer my connections to be hardwired.

Answer (score 1):

Computer memory/space is kind of like the old Hot Rodder's saying, "if too much horsepower is good, then too much is perfect."

In other words, if you ask the question and can afford it **always** get more memory/space on any computing device than you think you might need. Often times you will end up needing it.

Answer (score 1):

Using iCloud does **not** add extra space to the device, at least not in the same sense as extra 64GB do. Things never go directly to iCloud: any new photos or videos have to be kept on the device for some time, until they are uploaded to there and removed from here. Uploading requires time and good internet connection and therefore is not always available, besides, free iCloud only gives 5GB (which is nothing for photo storage purposes), any extra space has to be monthly paid for.

Your choice is basically as follows: how many photos and videos will you take before you bring the phone to a place with good and cheap internet connection? iCloud can not help when phone is on roaming and without WiFi. For any period without WiFi or unlimited/supercheap LTE, count on phone's own storage only.